# can I generate a keystore to use with someone else's workspace?

Tags: java, tomcat6, struts-1, java-6

I've inherited someone's java project and haven't touched java for almost 10 years now.
We started with a clean workspace, opened up the code, and are having trouble with the Keystore file.
We used the cmd prompt to create a new keystore file, and put in a new password, but the errors are complaining that the password verification failed. I don't know the previous password though, can anyone guide on what we should do?

We're running jdk 1.6.0.18 (I know it's old, but it's we have to at least go into maintenance mode before we update .. .. if we go to 1.6.0.45 that may require code changes right?), struts 1.38, tomcat 6.0

My errors/server logs are as follows:

```
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;.;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\gwongwon\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:coiWeb' did not find a matching property.
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:casTest' did not find a matching property.
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getKeystore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\Users\gwongwon/.keystore due to Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:771)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:296)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:544)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:769)
    ... 20 more
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:771)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:296)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:544)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:769)
    ... 20 more
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 580 ms
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/SingleSignOutFilter/artifactParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/artifactParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/service'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/service'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/artifactParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/artifactParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/serviceParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/serviceParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/encodeServiceUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/encodeServiceUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/exceptionOnValidationFailure'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/exceptionOnValidationFailure'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/redirectAfterValidation'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/redirectAfterValidation'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/useSession'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/useSession'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/acceptAnyProxy'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/acceptAnyProxy'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/allowedProxyChains'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/allowedProxyChains'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/proxyCallbackUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/proxyCallbackUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/renew'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/renew'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/proxyReceptorUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/proxyReceptorUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter/millisBetweenCleanUps'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/millisBetweenCleanUps'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/AuthenticationFilter/service'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/service'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/AuthenticationFilter/artifactParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/artifactParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/AuthenticationFilter/serviceParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/serviceParameterName'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/AuthenticationFilter/encodeServiceUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/encodeServiceUrl'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/AuthenticationFilter/gatewayStorageClass'; Returning null.
[WARN] No value found in context for: 'java:comp/env/cas/gatewayStorageClass'; Returning null.
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: StartUpServlet: C:\Users\gwongwon\dpsWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\coiWeb\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: StartUpServlet: edu.miami.it.coi
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: StartUpServlet: initDataSource() -> successful; lookup name = jdbc/tmDB2EVDevlV5
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: StartUpServlet: testPoolConnection() -> db2 rs = 001
[INFO] Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/C:/Users/gwongwon/dpsWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/coiWeb/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getKeystore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\Users\gwongwon/.keystore due to Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:771)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:296)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:544)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:769)
    ... 20 more
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:771)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:296)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:544)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:769)
    ... 20 more
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/10  config=null
Aug 9, 2013 1:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 14565 ms
```

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. Are you using a new key store that you created or not? How did you create the key and certificate in the new key store? Why does it matter that you don't know the previous password if you are working with a completely new key store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the password that Tomcat uses to open the keystore. See the Tomcat documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration).

Specifically, in the `<tomcat install location>/conf/server.xml` file, find the `Connector` xml tag where the keystore file is specified and change the `keystorePass` attribute.

Alternatively, look in the configuration file for what the password is currently set to and change your keystore's password to that.

Comment: That did it. 
Also, I found out that Tomcat's default password is changeit. So I re-created the keystore file, with this password and bingo. Thanks!